# SQLである列の値が1になったら、新しい番号でグループを採番したい

Tags: sql

ある列の値が1になったら、新しい番号でグループを採番したいのですが、
SQLを用いて実装できるかご存じでしょうか。

例えば、Aのようなデータがあったときに、Bのようなデータを作成したいです。

lag、first_valueのようなウィンドウ関数を用いてもうまくいかないので、
ならばpl/sqlかなと思っていますが、実現可能な実装方法が見つかりません。

【データA】

```
列1 列2
A   1
A   2
A   3
A   1
A   2
A   3
```

【データB】

```
列1 列2 列3
A   1   1
A   2   1
A   3   1
A   1   2
A   2   2
A   3   2
```

Comment: 行の順番は何で決まりますか。ID列などがあるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

主キーや更新日時などで順序を保証しているならば、副問い合わせで実現できます。

下記のSQLはOracleで更新日時順(updatカラム)に並べ、piyoカラムが1になる度に採番をカウントアップするサンプルコードです。

**SQL**

```
select src.*,
      (select nvl(sum(1), 0)
       from hoge tmp
       -- where tmp.rowid <= src.rowid -- ROWIDで無理矢理採番
       where tmp.updat <= src.updat  -- 更新日時順で採番
       and   tmp.piyo = 1) group_value
from   hoge src
order by updat;
```

**構成**

```
create table hoge (
  fuga char(1),
  piyo number(1),
  updat date
);

insert into hoge values ('A', 1, sysdate);
insert into hoge values ('A', 2, sysdate + 1);
insert into hoge values ('A', 3, sysdate + 2);
insert into hoge values ('A', 1, sysdate + 3);
insert into hoge values ('A', 2, sysdate + 4);
insert into hoge values ('A', 3, sysdate + 5);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/22c1f6/11)

なお行の順番を指定していない場合はSQLで取得する行の順序が保証されていません。
DBエンジンが発行する一意キーとしてOracleやSQLiteではrowidが、postgresqlではctidが使えますが、データ移行などで値が変わってしまいますのでこれらの一意キーに依存した設計はせず、主キーを作ることをおすすめします。

Answer (score 1):

#### 考え方

「ある列」の値が1ならば1、それ以外なら0を列Xとして、先頭行から当該行までの列Xの合計を求めて「新しい番号」とする方法です。

#### SQLの例

```
with TMPTBL(NO, C1, C2, X) as (
    select
            NO, C1, C2, case C2 when 1 THEN 1 else 0 end as X 
    from TARTGET_TABLE
)
select
    NO, C1, C2, sum(X) over(order by NO rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as 新しい番号
from TMPTBL
order by NO;
```

対象のテーブルはTARTGET_TABLEで、列名はC1とC2です。「ある列」はC2です。
ソートのキーとなる列NOを加えています。
unbounded precedingは先頭行
current rowは現在行です。

#### 実行例

```
with TARTGET_TABLE(NO, C1, C2) as (
    select 1, 'A', 1 union all
    select 2, 'A', 2 union all
    select 3, 'A', 3 union all
    select 4, 'A', 1 union all
    select 5, 'A', 2 union all
    select 6, 'A', 3 union all
    select 7, 'A', 4 union all
    select 8, 'A', 1
)
, TMPTBL(NO, C1, C2, X) as (
    select
            NO, C1, C2, case C2 when 1 THEN 1 else 0 end as X 
    from TARTGET_TABLE
)
select
    NO, C1, C2, sum(X) over(order by NO rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as 新しい番号
from TMPTBL
order by NO;

+----+----+----+-----------------+
| NO | C1 | C2 | 新しい番号      |
+----+----+----+-----------------+
|  1 | A  |  1 |               1 |
|  2 | A  |  2 |               1 |
|  3 | A  |  3 |               1 |
|  4 | A  |  1 |               2 |
|  5 | A  |  2 |               2 |
|  6 | A  |  3 |               2 |
|  7 | A  |  4 |               2 |
|  8 | A  |  1 |               3 |
+----+----+----+-----------------+
```

試したDBMSはMariaDBの10.5.9です。